# Windows/Gradle: tree-command shows no java files

Tags: java, testing, gradle

When I call the command 'tree' in my Windows-Terminal. It shows no java files in the folders:

[image: project file tree]

But they are clearly located in the folder when i open it without cmd.

In addition, gradle cant find this classes and cant test them. It says "NO SOURCE". The command 'gradle test' shows this:

[image: compilation output]

Comment: the folder? Which folder? Why did you create a project directly under c:\ rather than creating a directory for your project?

Comment: the src-folder is empty in cmd. and i creted the project on my Desktop, idk why it doesnt show..

Comment: tree on windows only lists the directories and not the files within

Comment: Thanks you, got my back!